# border on submit button image

Tags: html

I trying to get the image border to go away on a submit button and just can't seem to find the magic code to fix it.

```
<input name="Insert" type="image" id="Insert" alt="Register" 
          width="189" height="38" border="0" 
          src="../../images/register.png" 
          onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Insert','','../../images/register_f2.png',1)" 
          onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style="border: 0px;"` should do it.

Comment: That was it... I'm sure glad it was an easy one!

Answer (score 1):

[Works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/JdYYm/)

You may have some CSS that is being set by a selector with more specificity.

Use an inspection tool like Firebug to examine the exact CSS being applied.